# How to resize a pop up based on a loaded text in sencha?

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is my container where I want to load text, this code is inside a modal (pop up) I need that my pop up take the text height that was loaded.

```
Ext.define('Base.view.Notes', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'notes',
config: {
  modal: true,
  scrollable: null,
  itemId: 'generalNotesContainer',
  width: '90%',
  height: '90%',
  margin: '2em 5% 5% 5%',
  maxHeight: "90%",
  minHeight: "90%",
  floating: true,
  centered: true,
 layout: 'vbox',
items: [
    //other item
   {
     xtype: 'container',
     itemId: 'generalNotesContent',
     padding: "10",
     scrollable: true,
     flex: true,
     html: ''
   }
  ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Ext.window.MessageBox** and dont give any configs like height,width.It will handle dimensions as per its content.Currently you have used Container as parent,replace it by messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

I got to resize the pop up doing this:

```
Ext.define('Base.controller.WorkOrders', {
  config: {
    refs: {
      woView: 'woview',
      generalNotesContent: 'container#generalNotesContent',
    },
    control:{
      woView:{
         activate: 'woViewActivate'
      }
    }
},
woViewActivate: function(){

  this.loadNotes();
},
loadNotes: function(){

var gNotesView = Ext.widget('notes');
Ext.Viewport.add(gNotesView);


var html = "<div>My html</div>" 
this.getGeneralNotesContent().setHtml(html);
var NotesHtml = this.getGeneralNotesContent();
this.getGeneralNotesContent().setHeight(NotesHtml.innerHtmlElement.dom.scrollHeight);
//if it is needed extra height we can do this 
//var extraHeight= 70;
//this.getGeneralNotesContent().setHeight(NotesHtml.innerHtmlElement.dom.scrollHeight+ extraHeight);
gNotesView.show();

}
```

[this is how how looks my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQL54.png)